# How do I make a subcollection of user data in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an Hospital App in flutter. My goal is to configure firebase in such a way that the root collection is named User/uid(uid which is automatically generated when user is created)/someText/documentID(automatically generated by Firebase). This is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:mgm_app/models/vaccList.dart';


class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  CollectionReference userReg = Firestore.instance.collection('User');
  CollectionReference vaccTaken = Firestore.instance.collection('User').document(uid).collection('Vaccine Administered');

  Future regUserData(String email) async {
    return await userReg.document(uid).setData({
      'email': email,
    });
  }

  Future updateUserData(String vaccName,String dateAdmin) async {
  return await vaccTaken.document().setData({
     'name': vaccName,
      'vaccine given': dateAdmin,
  }
 );
  }
```

When a new user registers, a document with their uid is automatically created in the User collection. But when I'm trying to enter some personal data in the folder User/uid/VaccineAdmnistered,
I am not able to pass the value of the current user uid on this line of code

```
Firestore.instance.collection('User').document(uid).collection('Vaccine Administered');
```

The error i'm getting is

```
Only static members can be accessed in initializers.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `uid` inside the method `document` before the constructor is called. Therefore do the following:

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

  CollectionReference vaccTaken = Firestore.instance.collection('User');
  Future regUserData(String email) async {
    return await vaccTaken.document(uid).setData({
      'email': email,
    });
  }

  Future updateUserData(String vaccName,String dateAdmin) async {
  return await vaccTaken.document(uid).collection('Vaccine Administered').document().setData({
     'name': vaccName,
      'vaccine given': dateAdmin,
  }
 );
  }
```

Create a variable `vaccTaken` which will reference the collection `User`, then inside the method `updateUserData` access the `uid`.